# how to create a hook with navigation properties for useContext react-native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Thank you very much in advance
I have a native reagent application that is in the following order of components:

app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Routes } from './src/routes';
import { AppProvider } from './src/hooks';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <AppProvider>
        <Routes />
      </AppProvider>
  );
}
```

I just needed to use the navigation properties inside a hooks:
hook/index.tsx

```
import React, { ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

import {
  NavigationContainer,
  NavigationContext,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { AuthProvider } from './auth';
import { CommonProvider } from './common';


interface AppProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

function AppProvider({ children }: AppProviderProps) {
  return (
      <CommonProvider>
        <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
      </CommonProvider>
    </NavigationProvider>
  );
}

export { AppProvider };
```

hook example:
hook/CommonProvider.tsx:

```
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

type CommonContextData = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  setIsLoading: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

interface CommonProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const CommonContext = createContext<CommonContextData>({} as CommonContextData);

function CommonProvider({ children }: CommonProviderProps) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  //const {navigate} = useNavigation()//here I could use the navigation methods ???????
  return (
    <CommonContext.Provider value={{ isLoading, setIsLoading }}>
      {children}
    </CommonContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useCommon(): CommonContextData {
  const context = useContext(CommonContext);
  return context;
}

export { CommonProvider, useCommon };
```

how would I do the following implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to wrap the Root component with the NavigationContainer. Once done, you can use the useNavigation hook in any child component.
For instance inside the CommonProvider you can use the hook useEffect in that way.

```
const navigation = useNavigation(); 

useEffect(()=>{
  navigation.navigate('YourNextScreenName')
}, [navigation])
```

Comment: thank you in advance, but if I wrap the component

      <Routes >
        <AppProvider/>
      </Routes >
the routes were without the context no?

Comment: I mean something like that: 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppProvider>
        <Routes />
      </AppProvider>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Comment: I tried it and even managed to hook it but I get the following error when using the navigate method:
```
The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet. This might happen if you don't have a navigator mounted, or if the navigator hasn't finished mounting. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#handling-initialization for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as follows:
persist a file of
**routes/RootNavigation.ts**

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();

export function navigate(name: string, params: any) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name,params);
  }
}
```

in my case what contains the centralization of routes in the file add the
**navigationRef**, no NavigationContainer:
**routes/index.tsx**

```
   ...
   <NavigationContainer linking={linking} independent ref={navigationRef}>
   ...
```

using in file any hook:

```
...
  function handleMovePage() {
    // navigation.navigate('SignIn');
    RootNavigation.navigate('SelectArea', { userName: 'Lucy' });
  }
...
```

reference:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-context/